# JS strict shorthand comparison

Tags: javascript, comparison, shorthand

In the following example, we can evaluate `foo` to being truthy elegantly:

```
const foo = 'bar';
if (foo) { // clearer than (foo !== undefined)
  // -> executes
}
```

However, this actually evaluates as `(foo != undefined)`, as shown in the following example:

```
const foo = 0;
if (foo) { 
  // -> doesn't execute
}
```

In this example, I would want to `foo` to be truthy.

Is there any shorthand strict comparison that would evaluate `===` instead of `==`? The following becomes cumbersome:

```
const exists = (foo !== undefined && bar !== undefined && lorem !== undefined);
```

Comment: How would `(foo)` be anything other than just `"bar"` in that example? And the results you're getting seems more like the value is "truthy/falsy", not `undefined` ?

Comment: ^ note that "not-not" is still not strict.

Comment: Are you trying to see if a variable is defined, or assigned a value other than `undefined`?

Comment: @adeneo, the use cases suggest that, but i would not rely on that.

Comment: @adeneo I declared a static variable for the purpose of demonstration. In a real use cases the value would be dynamic. Edit: I had a type on wanting `foo` to evaulate to `true`. Fixed that.

Comment: The confusing part was that just wrapping a variable in parentheses would spit out a boolean? Regardless of what the value actually is, it generally wouldn't do that, `(foo)` doesn't magically become `true` ?

Comment: To answer the question, there is no good shorthand way to check for strict comparison, you have to use `===`

Comment: `The confusing part was that just wrapping a variable in parentheses would spit out a boolean?` Yes it does, this is used all the time and is even enforced in several popular JS linting patterns.

Comment: @dthree: No, it does not. `exists` evaluates to `'bar'` and `0` respectively, unless you are doing something else than what you've shown.

Comment: @Bergi good point... this is embarrassing... I suppose I have always used multiple comparisons `(foo && bar)` and so assumed it always evaulated to a boolean if wrapped in parens. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not aware of a shorthand for strict comparison you could easily check against `null` and `undefined` with a small helper function. I'm sure you are aware of this, but others looking up this question might not.

Instead of

```
const exists = (foo !== undefined && bar !== undefined && lorem !== undefined);
```

you'd be able to write:

```
const exists = [foo, bar, lorem].every(check);
```

Snippet with the function and some tests:

```js
var foo, bar, lorem, exists;

function check(arg) {
  return arg != null;
}

foo = "bar";
bar = "lorem";
lorem = "ipsum";
exists = [foo, bar, lorem].every(check);
document.getElementById("output-one").innerHTML = exists;

foo = 0;
bar = 0;
lorem = "ipsum";
exists = [foo, bar, lorem].every(check);
document.getElementById("output-two").innerHTML = exists;

foo = 0;
bar = 0;
var soab;
exists = [foo, bar, soab].every(check);
document.getElementById("output-foo").innerHTML = exists;
```

```html
<p id="output-one"></p>
<p id="output-two"></p>
<p id="output-foo"></p>
```

*As Bergi pointed out in the comments, along with two major improvements, of course you could also check for !== undefined to keep this function closer to the question's behaviour.*

Comment: Notice that `!= null` and `!== undefined` ar two different animals. Also you should simplify your `check` function to simply `return` the result of the comparison instead of using a lengthy and confusing `if` statement.

Comment: Even better: `[foo, bar, lorem].every(check)`

Comment: beautiful, gonna edit that! but would keep the check for == null, since it is true for null and undefined, but false for int 0? sorry, not quite sure if I got your first comment.

Comment: OP has used `!== undefined`, which has a different result than your if you pass in `null`. That might or might not be wanted. Also, regarding the simplifcation, I meant `function check(x) { return x != null; }`

Comment: got it, neat! thanks a thousand & this pretty much is your answer now! ;>